# How to integrate Twilio in Android

Tags: php, android, api, twilio

I'm trying out the [Twilio Android Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/twilio-application), and I've gotten to the end of the Making an outgoing call section in Java, but for some reason. I'm not getting success in Android.

I've created a php Api too for token, but that token isn't giving capability code to me. This api is on our local server i.e. localhost.

I'm giving source code of my project too

```
public class MonkeyPhone implements Twilio.InitListener, DeviceListener,
    ConnectionListener {
private static final String TAG = "MonkeyPhone";
private Device device;
private Connection connection;
private final Context context;
private BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener;
private BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener;
private Connection pendingIncomingConnection;
InputMethodManager imm;
private boolean speakerEnabled;
private boolean muteEnabled;
static String capabilityToken;
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

public interface BasicConnectionListener {
    public void onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();

    public void onConnectionConnecting();

    public void onConnectionConnected();

    public void onConnectionFailedConnecting(Exception error);

    public void onConnectionDisconnecting();

    public void onConnectionDisconnected();

    public void onConnectionFailed(Exception error);
}

 public interface BasicDeviceListener {
    public void onDeviceStartedListening();

    public void onDeviceStoppedListening(Exception error);
 }

public MonkeyPhone(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    Twilio.initialize(context, this /* Twilio.InitListener */);
}

public void setListeners(BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener,
        BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener) {
    this.basicConnectionListener = basicConnectionListener;
    this.basicDeviceListener = basicDeviceListener;
}

/* Twilio.InitListener method */
@Override
public void onInitialized() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Twilio SDK is ready");
    try {
        // String capabilityToken =
        // HttpHelper.httpGet("http://------/mobile/auth.php");
         //capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet("http:------/auth.php");
        capabilityToken = HttpHelper
                .httpGet("http://www.companyfoo.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        System.out.println(capabilityToken);
        device = Twilio
                .createDevice(capabilityToken, null /* DeviceListener */);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "Failed to obtain capability token: "
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
/* Twilio.InitListener method */
@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Twilio SDK couldn't start: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
@Override
protected void finalize() {
    if (device != null)
        device.release();
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
}
// To Make Calls
public void connect(String phoneNumber) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Dialing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
     connection = device.connect(parameters, null /* ConnectionListener */);
        if (connection == null)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    try 
    {
        // capabilityToken =
        // HttpHelper.httpGet("http://------/mobile/auth.php");
     //         capabilityToken = HttpHelper
    //  .httpGet("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-     01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json");
        //device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, null /* DeviceListener */);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        device.disconnectAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// To Disconnect Phone
public void disconnect() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Call Disconnected...",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
        connection = null; 

        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnecting();
    }
}
public void setSpeakerEnabled(boolean speakerEnabled) {
    if (speakerEnabled != this.speakerEnabled) {
        this.speakerEnabled = speakerEnabled;
        updateAudioRoute();
    }
}
private void updateAudioRoute() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(speakerEnabled);
}
public void setMuteEnabled(boolean muteEnabled) {
    if (muteEnabled != this.muteEnabled) {
        this.muteEnabled = muteEnabled;
        updateAudioRouteForMute();
    }
}
private void updateAudioRouteForMute() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(muteEnabled);
}
public State status() {
    connection.getState();
    State statusHere = connection.getState();
    return statusHere;
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Connection arg0) {
    updateAudioRoute();
    updateAudioRouteForMute();
    if (basicConnectionListener != null) {
        basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnected();
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnecting(Connection arg0) {
    if (basicConnectionListener != null) {
        basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnecting();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection) {
    if (inConnection == connection) {
        connection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnected();
    } else if (inConnection == pendingIncomingConnection) {
        pendingIncomingConnection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection, int arg1,
        String inErrorMessage) {
    if (inConnection == connection) {
        connection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener
                    .onConnectionFailedConnecting(new Exception(
                            inErrorMessage));
    }
}
@Override
public void onPresenceChanged(Device arg0, PresenceEvent arg1) {

}
@Override
public void onStartListening(Device arg0) {
    if (basicDeviceListener != null) {
        basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStartedListening();
    }
}
@Override
public void onStopListening(Device arg0) {
    if (basicDeviceListener != null) {
        basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStoppedListening(null);
    }
}
@Override
public void onStopListening(Device arg0, int arg1, String arg2) {

}
@Override
public boolean receivePresenceEvents(Device arg0) {
    return false;
}
}
```

And **php** code is

```
 <?php

 require_once('Services/Twilio/Capability.php');
// Your API credentials from Account Dashboard here
$accountSid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$authToken = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
$appSid = 'APzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';

 $capability = new Services_Twilio_Capability($accountSid, $authToken);
 // give this app permissions
 $capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
 // generate token that lasts for 5 minutes
 $token = $capability->generateToken(300);

  ?>`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any error log you see if not getting success ?

Comment: There is no error, Just getting null value of capability token

Comment: Try Twilios DEV TOOLS on their web site to check is there any error or not.. Check this [link](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/message-create)

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  If you are not getting a capability token then you're not going to be able to make or receive calls through Twilio client.  Can you show the PHP code you are using to generate the capability token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

It does not look like you are echoing the token out in your PHP file.  If you load that PHP file in a browser, does the [capability token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) get generated?  If not, try adding `echo $token` after you generate the token.

Comment: We are getting the token but not able to get the capability token from the link: http://companyfoo.com/token which will make connection with android APP and twilio

Comment: OK so just to clarify, if you open the PHP page in a browser window the capability token gets rendered, but your not able to reterive it in your Android app?  Is there an exception being thrown by HttpHelper?

Answer (score 2):

**Now I can call easily by using this call:**

```
package com.twilio.example.hellomonkey;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.twilio.client.Connection;
import com.twilio.client.Connection.State;
import com.twilio.client.ConnectionListener;
import com.twilio.client.Device;
import com.twilio.client.DeviceListener;
import com.twilio.client.PresenceEvent;
import com.twilio.client.Twilio;
public class MonkeyPhone implements Twilio.InitListener, DeviceListener, ConnectionListener {
private static final String TAG = "MonkeyPhone";
private Device device;
private Connection connection;
private final Context context;
private BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener;
private BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener;
private Connection pendingIncomingConnection;
InputMethodManager imm;
private boolean speakerEnabled;
private boolean muteEnabled;
static String capabilityToken;

public interface BasicConnectionListener {
    public void onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();

    public void onConnectionConnecting();

    public void onConnectionConnected();

    public void onConnectionFailedConnecting(Exception error);

    public void onConnectionDisconnecting();

    public void onConnectionDisconnected();

    public void onConnectionFailed(Exception error);
}

public interface BasicDeviceListener {
    public void onDeviceStartedListening();

    public void onDeviceStoppedListening(Exception error);
}

public MonkeyPhone(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    Twilio.initialize(context, this /* Twilio.InitListener */);
}

public void setListeners(BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener, BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener) {
    this.basicConnectionListener = basicConnectionListener;
    this.basicDeviceListener = basicDeviceListener;
}

/* Twilio.InitListener method */
@Override
public void onInitialized() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Twilio SDK is ready");
    try {
        // String capabilityToken =
        // HttpHelper.httpGet("http://------/mobile/auth.php");
        capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet("your php url which gives you token");

        device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, null /* DeviceListener */);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to obtain capability token: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

/* Twilio.InitListener method */
@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Twilio SDK couldn't start: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}

@Override
protected void finalize() {
    if (device != null)
        device.release();
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
}

// To Make Calls

public void connect(String phoneNumber) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Dialing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    //String capabilityToken;
    try {
        // capabilityToken =
        // HttpHelper.httpGet("http://------/mobile/auth.php");
        //capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet("your php url which gives you token");

        //device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, null /* DeviceListener */);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        device.disconnectAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection = device.connect(parameters, null /* ConnectionListener */);
    if (connection == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
    }
}

// To Disconnect Phone
public void disconnect() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Call Disconnected...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
        connection = null; // will null out in onDisconnected()

        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnecting();
    }
}

public void setSpeakerEnabled(boolean speakerEnabled) {
    if (speakerEnabled != this.speakerEnabled) {
        this.speakerEnabled = speakerEnabled;
        updateAudioRoute();
    }
}

private void updateAudioRoute() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(speakerEnabled);
}

public void setMuteEnabled(boolean muteEnabled) {
    if (muteEnabled != this.muteEnabled) {
        this.muteEnabled = muteEnabled;
        updateAudioRouteForMute();
    }
}

private void updateAudioRouteForMute() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(muteEnabled);
}

public State status() {
    connection.getState();
    State statusHere = connection.getState();
    return statusHere;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Connection arg0) {
    updateAudioRoute();
    updateAudioRouteForMute();
    if (basicConnectionListener != null) {
        basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnected();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnecting(Connection arg0) {
    if (basicConnectionListener != null) {
        basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnecting();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection) {
    if (inConnection == connection) {
        connection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnected();
    } else if (inConnection == pendingIncomingConnection) {
        pendingIncomingConnection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection, int arg1, String inErrorMessage) {
    if (inConnection == connection) {
        connection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onConnectionFailedConnecting(new Exception(inErrorMessage));
    }

}

@Override
public void onPresenceChanged(Device arg0, PresenceEvent arg1) {

}

@Override
public void onStartListening(Device arg0) {
    if (basicDeviceListener != null) {
        basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStartedListening();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStopListening(Device arg0) {
    if (basicDeviceListener != null) {
        basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStoppedListening(null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStopListening(Device arg0, int arg1, String arg2) {

}

@Override
public boolean receivePresenceEvents(Device arg0) {
    return false;
}

}
```